# POJO Mapping in JOOQ regardless of parameter order

Tags: java, database, mapping, record, jooq

When I generate the JOOQ POJOs, the constructor follows the same order for the parameters as the fields in the database table.

When querying the table and using `fetchInto` this works fine, as long as the order of the POJO constructor parameters and the order of the fields in the database table are the same.

```java
return create
      .select()
      .from(KEY)
      .fetchInto(Key.class);
```

How can I map the query above into `Key.class` regardless of the constructor parameter order? 
E.g. can I use something like mapstruct in conjunction with JOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate your constructor with `@java.beans.ConstructorProperties`. We also support Java 8's parameter name reflection (see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4627), but that does not seem as reliable, as it depends on flags you set when compiling your own code.

See also the documentation of [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, `@java.beans.ConstructorProperties` is not an option for the autogenerated POJOs and I'm not in a position where I can use reflection, but I'll look into the DefautlRecordMapper 

Comment: @emazzotta: That's a good hint. We should definitely support generating that annotation: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10013. In the meantime, you can override `JavaGenerator.generatePojoMultiConstructor()` to generate this annotation on all immutable POJOs yourself.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce my initial problem where the select query is unable to automatically map its result to the POJO due to the table attributes and POJO constructor parameters being in a different order. I'll accept your answer and comment back if anything changes.

Comment: @emazzotta: The only case when this could ever happen is when the generated code (tables, records, pojos) is not in sync, or you've discovered a rare bug.

Comment: Okay, so indeed the issue was not fixed. I updated my question, maybe you could help me accomplishing the mapping via Mapstruct. It seems I didn't quite understand how a record mapper works yet.

Comment: @emazzotta: I think this is a substantially different question now. Can you please revert and ask a new question? Stack Overflow works best as a Q&A, not like a discussion forum.

Comment: Of course: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61057659/use-mapstruct-as-recordmapper-for-jooq