# Use Mapstruct as RecordMapper for JOOQ

Tags: java, database, mapping, record, jooq

I would like to implement my own `RecordMapper` and use Mapstruct to map the Record to the POJO. I don't quite understand how to accomplish this. I followed this part of the docs: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/

My mapper looks like this:

```
public class LanguageMapper<R extends Record, E> implements RecordMapper<R, Language> {

  @Override
  public Language map(R record) {
    LanguageRecord languageRecord = (LanguageRecord) record;

    // this is just an example, in the future this is the kind of mapping that would be performed automatically via mapstruct
    return new Language(
             languageRecord.getId(), 
             languageRecord.getNamespaceId(), 
             languageRecord.getLanguage(), 
             languageRecord.getCountryCode(), 
             languageRecord.getLanguageTag()
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is that as a `record` I'm not actually getting a `LanguageRecord` but a `RecordImpl` of my language table and can thus not cast `record` to `LanguageRecord`. Any idea what I need to change?

What's interesting when using the `RecordImpl` is, if I do something like this

```
record.get(LANGUAGE.LANGUAGE_TAG);
```

It will already get the wrong information (it's getting the LANGUAGE.NAMESPACE_ID). Thus when getting it like this and then mapping it to the POJO it will be wrong as well.

(Created this question based on this question [POJO Mapping in JOOQ regardless of parameter order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926102/pojo-mapping-in-jooq-regardless-of-parameter-order))

Comment: 1) I'm not sure how MapStruct relates to your question here. 2) You've already answered the part where you cannot cast. A `RecordMapperProvider` is a *generic, global* provider for *all* `RecordMapper` instances, not just the one you're interested in for a single query execution. The reason wyh you're getting the wrong data cannot be answered from the facts that you've presented in your question so far. May I recommend to read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It is difficult to see what you're trying to do and what exactly fails from your question so far

Comment: Sorry Lukas, I did some digging and it turns out in the end the issue I had was simply caused by performing a select with an asterisk instead of specifying the individual fields. Once I specified the fields, the POJO mapping works just fine. My problem is solved now.

Comment: Using an explicit asterisk will produce the columns in the order in which they're defined in the SQL table. If the generated code is not in sync with the SQL table, the generated order might not be correct, so jOOQ would be expecting a different order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was a result of the problem described here: [POJO Mapping in JOOQ regardless of parameter order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926102/pojo-mapping-in-jooq-regardless-of-parameter-order)

But it turns out that the problem can be solved without even needing any sort of mapper.

Problem:
If JOOQ generates POJOs/Records/etc. based on a database which has the attributes of a table in a certain order, but the order of the attributes changes after JOOQ already generated the POJOs/Records/etc. it's possible that a `SELECT *` will not map the fields to the correct attributes in the POJOs

E.g. The POJO `Language` has the attributes `country` and `language` and suddenly `Language` contains the table value of `country` in `Lanugage.getLanguage()` and the table value of `lanugage` in `Language.getCountry()`.

This issue can be solved by specifying an order (regardless what the actual order of the database fields are) in the `SELECT`-statement, like `SELECT language, country`.

Answer (score 1):

I generated my Record classes and POJOs with jOOQ codegen and my minimal mapper just worked

```java
@Mapper
public interface FooMapper extends RecordMapper<FooRecord, Foo>, RecordUnmapper<Foo, FooRecord> {
}
```

It warns about unmapped fields, but you can suppress that with.

```java
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for Generics for mapping source and target as of now :
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/583

Example wrokaround:

https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/631

You need to use concrete classes when defining the mapper.